# Finding the average/mean value of numbers pulled from an xml file

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, average

I have code that extracts data out of an XML file. I want to find the average / mean value for each of the extracted values (`XMax`, `XMin`, `YMax`, `YMin`, `ZMax`, `ZMin`)

Here is how I extracted the six values:

```
var query = from file in fileEntries
            let doc = XDocument.Load(file) 
            let x = doc.Descendants("XAxisCalib").Single() 
            let y = doc.Descendants("YAxisCalib").Single() 
            let z = doc.Descendants("ZAxisCalib").Single() 
            select new
            {
                XMax = x.Element("Max").Value, 
                XMin = x.Element("Min").Value, 
                YMax = y.Element("Max").Value, 
                YMin = y.Element("Min").Value, 
                ZMax = z.Element("Max").Value, 
                ZMin = z.Element("Min").Value 
            };
```

Am I on the right track with this average for XMax:

```
 var Average1 =
    from a in query
    select new 
    { AvgMaxX =  a.Average(a => a.XMax) };
```

Comment: I want to find the mean of the 6 values extracted out.

Comment: @Casey: What have you tried?  Can you post the code that you've written to try to find the average?  Simple googling will solve this problem, which shows you didn't research the question at all before asking it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746

Comment: See above for possible solution for just Xmax. Am I on right track?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var averageMaximumX = query.Average(t => t.XMax);
var averageMinimumX = query.Average(t => t.XMin);
var averageMaximumY = query.Average(t => t.YMax);
var averageMinimumY = query.Average(t => t.YMin);
var averageMaximumZ = query.Average(t => t.ZMax);
var averageMinimumZ = query.Average(t => t.ZMin);
```

EDIT: To convert the strings to doubles or decimals or whatever:

```
var averageMaximumX = query.Average(t => double.Parse(t.XMax));
//OR: var averageMaximumX = query.Average(t => decimal.Parse(t.XMax));
```

But I would actually do it in the select:

```
select new
{
    XMax = double.Parse(x.Element("Max").Value),
    XMin = double.Parse(x.Element("Min").Value),
// etc.
```

Comment: doesn't like this code alittle bit:

cannot convert type string to decimal
cannot convert type lambda expression to delegate type

Comment: I edited my answer to show how to get numeric types out of the strings that you get from the XML.

Comment: Thank you I got slipped up on converting from string to decimal.

Comment: It works, but I don't like the fact that you have to iterate through the collection 6 times :-S

Comment: Good point.  I wonder whether you could calculate all the averages on a single pass with Linq.  I can't think how to do it off the top of my head (end of a long day).  You could, of course, do it with a foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

is that helpful 
http://csharpbasic.blogspot.com/2008/08/exploring-linq-functions-select-min-max.html

Comment: Linking is fine, but please place the gist of the solution in your answer in case the link breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to hack your way into getting your answers, but I don't like this at all and I'm sure there is a proper way :

```
double aXMax = 0;
double aXMin = 0;
double aYMax = 0;
double aYMin = 0;
double aZMax = 0;
double aZMin = 0;

int count = (from file in fileEntries
        let doc = XDocument.Load(file) 
        let x = doc.Descendants("XAxisCalib").Single() 
        let y = doc.Descendants("YAxisCalib").Single() 
        let z = doc.Descendants("ZAxisCalib").Single() 
        select new
        {
            aXMax += x.Element("Max").Value, 
            aXMin += x.Element("Min").Value, 
            aYMax += y.Element("Max").Value, 
            aYMin += y.Element("Min").Value, 
            aZMax += z.Element("Max").Value, 
            aZMin += z.Element("Min").Value 
        }).Count();

aXMax /= (double)count;
aXMin /= (double)count;
aYMax /= (double)count;
aYMin /= (double)count;
aZMax /= (double)count;
aZMin /= (double)count;
```

Haven't tested it out, but it should work, even though it's SO ugly...

Comment: It won't work.  You can't define a value with += because there's nothing to start with.  Besides, anonymous types are immutable, so even if it's not in the context of the `new` statement, you can't use += on a property of an anonymous type.

Comment: Humn... I'll have to recall how I've done something like that in the past. But anyways, I'll delete the answer since it's so ugly :-P